# Python hashes differ between threads

Tags: python, hash, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm using Python 3.6 on Windows and have a parallelizable task that includes computing string hashes. This is basically a minimal version of my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def hash_some(foo):
    return hash(foo)


def main():
    hashes = Parallel(n_jobs=10)(delayed(hash_some)(s) for s in ['a', 'a', 'a'])

    print(hashes)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, for some reason this prints, e.g., the following:

```
[3220780809080710068, -561460911962106608, -1551910331007446174]
```

Where they clearly should all be the same.

The hashes don't always differ, and especially for a lower `n_job` value they often turn out the same but this is not guaranteed.

I know `hash()` uses a random seed per program invocation but why does it apparently use a different seed per thread? Is there any way I can set a fixed (but random) seed for all my threads? (I know about `PYTHONHASHSEED=0` but I'd prefer to find an in-code solution)

Comment: Temporary workaround for me right now is to use an explicit hash: `hashlib.md5(foo.encode()).hexdigest()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already explained, randomization of hash can be controlled with PYTHONHASHSEED, for more information take a read on [this](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-R). Now, if you want to control the behaviour by code and not with the python interpreter options or export that env. var a possible solution could be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import os
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'

def hash_some(foo):
    return hash(foo)

def main():
    hashes = Parallel(n_jobs=10)(delayed(hash_some)(s) for s in 'a' * 10000)

    print(set(hashes))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you comment the `os.environ` line you'll see the final set length won't be 1 anymore